# auto_test gives reporter error in testthat

Tags: r, testthat

I'm trying to force myself to do more unit testing on some data analysis projects where I don't really want to develop a package. So, I've been playing with the `testthat` R package. I have a `code` folder and inside it is a `src` and a `test` folder. In the `src` folder I have the file `add.R` that has this function:

```
add <- function(x,y){
    x+y
}
```

In the `test` folder I have the file `test-add.R` that contains this:

```
library(testthat)

test_that("adding numbers", {
    expect_equal(add(2,3), 5)
    expect_equal(add(5,5), 10)
})
```

The following works fine...

```
> source('code/src/add.R')
> test_file('code/test/test-add.R')
```

But I'd like to be able to use the `auto_test` function since as the project grows `source`/`test_file` will get tedious. But when I try `auto_test` I get this...

```
> auto_test('code/src', 'code/test')
Error in find_reporter(reporter) : attempt to apply non-function
```

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but what?

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
Running under: OS X 10.11.1 (El Capitan)

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] testthat_0.11.0.9000 knitr_1.12.3        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] lazyeval_0.1.10      R6_2.1.2             tools_3.2.3         
[4] withr_1.0.1          memoise_1.0.0        crayon_1.3.1        
[7] digest_0.6.9         devtools_1.10.0.9000
```

Comment: Would `testthat::test_dir("code/src")` fix your problem?

Comment: Thanks - not really - I'd still have to source the files, I'd have to have the code and test code together, and it wouldn't be automated

Comment: If I create the same files and folder structure, `auto_test()` runs fine for me. The only relevant difference in the R set up that I can see is in the version of testthat, where I use 0.11.0, while you seem to have a development version installed. Maybe you could try to install 0.11.0 from CRAN?

Comment: If you don't manage with `auto_test()`, you could add `source("../src/add.R")` to `test-add.R` and use `test_dir("code/test")` as suggested by ZNK.

Comment: Thanks @Stibu - if I use the CRAN version it works fine. If you want to propose that as a solution, I'll happily mark yours as the answer.

Comment: So this was really it... Thanks for the feedback. I have reported the issue on GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a problem of `testthat` version 0.11.0.9000. If I install this version from github, I get the same error message as you do:

```
auto_test('code/src', 'code/test')
## Error in find_reporter(reporter) : attempt to apply non-function
```

But with version 0.11.0 that can be installed from CRAN, your example runs fine:

```
auto_test('code/src', 'code/test')
## ..
## DONE
```